# Find similar named file

Tags: php, regex, glob

In PHP, how to search for a file with a similar name? There are three files: `file.csv`, `file.csv.1` and `olderfile.csv`.

How to find the files `file.csv` and `file.csv.1`?

Comment: What's the rules for "similar"? Is `file.csv`, `file1.csv`, `file.csv.1`, `1file.csv` all similar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depend on how you define "similar." And try use regular expression.

```
$filename = basename("/some/long/path/file.csv");
// Or other vars pointing to your actual file.

$pattern = '/(^file\.csv(?:\.\d|))/';

if(preg_match($pattern, $filename, $matches)){
    print_r($matches);
} else {
    echo "Not found.";
}
```

Comment: I agree about regex. A pattern like this would match all the cases mentioned, even something like file1.csv: `/^[\w\/]*\/([\w\d\.]*file[\d\.]*\.csv\.?[0-9]?)/`

Comment: I am not certain how complex it will require so just provide a simple pattern. And of course it could be more complex, when needed.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [glob()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php) function for this. This should work with the files you mentioned:

```
foreach (glob("file.csv*") as $filename) {
    echo "$filename\n";
}
```

Comment: Hey. I know about the glob. But it does not work in Windows.

Comment: Hmm, it should work on Windows too, unless maybe the glob rules are different. Could you post the actual code?

Comment: Check that "olderfile.csv" should not be include in the result: `glob("file.csv*")`

Comment: Right, if olderfile.csv should not be included, the pattern would indeed be as @YosvelQuintero wrote. I'm updating the answer.